# How to get ARRAY_CONSTRUCT as an ARRAY?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use the snowflake api to query my warehouse and get in response an array of values. In order to do I've used ARRAY_CONSTRUCT. However, instead of getting an array of string I'm getting a single string with values inside.

The relevant code:

```py
import snowflake.connector

class SnowflakeClient:
    def __init__(self, connection: Dict)
      self._connection = snowflake.connector.connect(..)
      self._cursor = self._connection.cursor()

    def execute_query(self, query: str) -> None:
        self._cursor.execute(query)

    def fetch_results(self, num_of_results: int) -> List:
        return self._cursor.fetchmany(num_of_results)
```

where the query I'm using is something like:

```
SELECT  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(col1, col2, col3) as some_value
FROM table1
```

And instead of getting - `[value1, value2, value3]`
I'm getting- `'[\n value1 \n value2 \n value3 ]'`

Any idea how can I change the query to get what I need?

Answer (score 0):

I check the documentation and you are correct
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html.

It does return like below. But in the Snowflake UI it does removes the newlines.

```
select array_construct(10, 20, 30);
+-----------------------------+
| ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(10, 20, 30) |
|-----------------------------|
| [                           |
|   10,                       |
|   20,                       |
|   30                        |
| ]                           |
+-----------------------------+
```

Now as this is python you are better trying this on your result object as below.

```
from snowflake.connector import DictCursor
cursor = con.cursor(DictCursor)
res = cursor.execute(<select query>)
result = cursor.fetchall()
result[0]
{'COLUMN_NAME': '[\n  100,\n  "abc"\n]'}
result[0]['COLUMN_NAME'].replace('\n','')
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks

Comment: that's not really the solution I was looking for. The thing is me as the client is unaware what the query is. So I was hoping to change the query itself and not the client.